# What find() exactly returns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I was testing a method with *qunit*, and i found something i didn't understand.

The function is checking if all descendants of  are scanned, i used a variable to calculate the number of occurrences.

```
test ("all body children highlilighted", function(){
        var body = $('<body><form><label>This is a label</label><input type="text" /></form><input type="text" /></body>') ;
        scan_body(body) ;

        var compteur = 0 ;

        body.find('*').each(function(idx, val){
                var past_color = $(this).css('background-color') ;
                var present_color = $(this).mouseenter().css('background-color') ;
                notEqual(past_color, present_color, "We expected the color of this element to be changed") ;
                compteur++ ;
        }) ;
        equal(compteur, 5, "5 expected !!!!") ;
}) ;
```

the final assertion is always false, *compteur* contains 2 always. Why ?

Comment: `find` isn't a part of either JavaScript or the DOM. Are you using jQuery? (Looks like it.) If so, I'd add the tag.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - he is, see second line of the code

Comment: @kamituel: That tells us he's using **some** library that uses the `$` symbol (there are several), not that he's necessarily using jQuery. I'd say from that, `find`, and `each`, it's *really really likely*, but we shouldn't have to guess.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - true, good thinking :)

Comment: @ elaich: Assuming jQuery, I would expect 4, not 5. (The form, the label, and two inputs; `find` finds *descendants* and so `body` doesn't count.) But 2 surprises me.

Comment: Are both inputs meant to be inside the form?

Comment: You need to console.log `$(body).find('*')` and you'll see why two.

Comment: @T.J Crowder I'm using jQuery yes,

Comment: @Tyron the second input is meant to be outside the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you're experiencing is because jQuery's `$()`, when used to parse HTML string, uses `innerHTML` internally (putting your HTML into a `<div>`). It is explained in jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2):

> When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. As mentioned, jQuery uses the browser"s .innerHTML property to parse the passed HTML and insert it into the current document. During this process, some browsers filter out certain elements such as <html>, <title>, or <head> elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be representative of the original string passed

And `innerHTML` strips out `<body>` if you try to put it into a `<div>` ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pk5Vt/)):

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<body><form></form></body>';
// div == <div><form></form></div>
```

If not for this, you would see `compteur` equal to 4, as per @T.J. Crowder [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20702104/782609).

Answer (score 2):

*(I'm assuming you're using jQuery.)*

This happens because the `body` tag is treated specially for some reason: What we're getting back *isn't* a `body` element, it's a `form` element and only has what's in the form (the label and the input). If you replace `body` with `div`, you'll get the expected result, which is 4 (not 5; `find` only finds *descendants*, so the top-level element wouldn't be counted).

I'm surprised to find `body` being treated specially, but that is what's happening.

This version using `body`, with irrelevant bits commented out, shows that what we get back is only the `form` and its contents (I added `id`s to the inputs so we could tell them apart):

```
function foo(){
    var body = $('<body><form><label>This is a label</label><input id="first" type="text" /></form><input id="second" type="text" /></body>') ;
    //scan_body(body) ;

    var compteur = 0 ;

    console.log("<code>body[0].tagName</code>: " + body[0].tagName);        
    body.find('*').each(function(idx, val){
        //var past_color = $(this).css('background-color') ;
        //var present_color = $(this).mouseenter().css('background-color') ;
        //notEqual(past_color, present_color, "We expected the color of this element to be changed") ;
        console.log(
          idx + ": " +
          this.tagName + 
          " (" + (this.id || "[no id]") +
          ")");
        compteur++ ;
    }) ;
    console.log("compteur = " + compteur);
}
foo();
```

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/uwELUMIZ/1/edit)

Result:

```
Using body
body[0].tagName: FORM
0: LABEL ([no id])
1: INPUT (first)
compteur = 2
```

But the exact same thing using `div` gives us the expected results (the div with all of the content) - [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/uwELUMIZ/2/edit):

```
Using div
body[0].tagName: DIV
0: FORM ([no id])
1: LABEL ([no id])
2: INPUT (first)
3: INPUT (second)
compteur = 4
```

Comment: Could you explain (or link to) why the `body` is being treated this way?

Comment: @Nunners: I wish I could. It surprises me.

Comment: @Nunners - I think if `<body>` is an empty element (like `$('<body/>')`), it's fine, but if `<body>` has any descendant, it's translucent.

Comment: @Nunners: Looks like the `body` part is being stripped out and we're just getting back the `form` element and its contents.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Just replicated that, if you add an element to the `form` it will then count 3. It seems to skip straight to the form, that does seem odd.

Comment: @kamituel do you know why that behavior occurs? It seems quite strange to me.

Comment: @Nunners - I wonder, maybe because of this: "When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. As mentioned, jQuery uses the browser"s .innerHTML property to parse the passed HTML and insert it into the current document. During this process, some browsers filter out certain elements such as  <html>,  <title>, or  <head> elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be representative of the original string passed.". ([source](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)).

Comment: @Nunners - yes, I guess that's because of how `innerHTML` works. See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pk5Vt/) for jQuery-less example.